# PHP echoing emptying string in $.ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get back data from an AJAX call. I tested with a string but it's returning empty. I just want to print the string to console on response.

JS:

```
makeRequest: function(sService, oData){
        var request = $.post(
            '../../Utils/utils/php/userQuery.php'
            ,{'sService' : sService, 'oData':  oData}
            ,'json'
        );
        request.done(function(oResult){
            // This is firing off, but is printing empty string
            console.log(JSON.stringify(oResult));
            var fail = errorHandler.check(oResult);
            if(!fail){
                // This is firing off, but is printing empty string
                console.log(oResult);
            } else{
                console.log(fail);
            }
        });
        request.fail(function(oResult){
            console.log("There was an error in retrieving service data");
        });
    }
```

PHP:

```
class request{
    private $sService;
    function _construct($sService){
        $_SESSION['user_Id'] = 100000;
        $this->$sService = $sService;
        switch($this->$sService){
            case 'follower':
                break;
            case 'followee':
                break;
            case 'promoter':
                break;
            case 'promotee':
                break;
            case 'note':
                // This should be hit and return "hit"
                echo json_encode("hit");
                break;
            case 'createFollowee':
                break;
            case 'createPromotee':
                break;
            case 'createNote':
                break;
            default:
                echo "ErrorCode: 4000";
                break;
        }
    }
}
$request = new request($_POST['sService']);
```

If I try to `$.parseJSON(oResult)` the response I get an error with parsing because it's empty. Where am I going wrong at?

ANSWER:

The updated code above works. There was several problems provided by answers.

1. I didn't add 2 _ to construct().[before: _construct after: __construct]
2. I didn't is $this to point to my global variable inside of my class.
3. I originally didn't initialize my class.
4. I wasn't passing my variable(s) to the construct when initializing class.

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Where is the instance for that class `request`?

Comment: have you checked the browser developer tools to check if the request actually transmits the correct values for `'sService'` and check the result before you stringify it? FYI: stringify is not needed before logging to the console.

Comment: I also think you want to do this `$this->sService = $_POST['sService'];`  With what you have there, I would expect that "ErrorCode: 4000" be echoed ($this->sService is currently null unless you change what I suggest)

Comment: `echo(json_encode('hit'));` You're asking for a json return but you're echoing plain text. just make it json encoded and you're good to go

Comment: I added the $this-> and added the json_encode(), but same results.

Comment: As a continuation of what @JensonMJohn said, I don't see where you initialized the `request` class. You'll need to initialize the class using `new request();`. Linking to the file, or using `include` or `require` from another php file does not automatically initialize your class. At the bottom of your file add `new request();`...

Comment: @War10ck, I added that at the bottom but nothing happened. I wasn't aware that I forgot to initialize my class. I'm nothing really sure if that is right though.

Comment: I think your code in your request class has one too many $'s. 

$this->$sService = $_POST['sService']; should be $this->sService = $_POST['sService']; shouldnt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the dev-tools of your browser to check the server response. Maybe the response is really empty?
2. You want to get JSON data, but you don't `json_encode` your output
3. PHP constructors start with **2** underscores: `__construct` (not `_construct`)
4. `$sService = $_POST['sService'];` should be `$this->sService = $_POST['sService'];`
5. The constructor won't be called when you don't initialize your class with `new request();`

Answer (score 0):

This could be your class constructor not running properly. The correct syntax of declaring the constructor function is `function __construct()` (**two underscores** preceded) or `function theClassName()`. Check [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

http://codepad.viper-7.com/k3vclY - Nothing/empty output with `_construct()` of one underscore
http://codepad.viper-7.com/vabqqL - Something output with `__construct()` of two underscores